# How to handle multiple event types from one class in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

In JavaFX, is it possible to handle multiple event types (e.g. ActionEvent, MouseEvent, etc.) from one class, without anonymous EventHandlers? I tried the following, but that just created a compile-time error.

```
public class GUI extends Application implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>,
                                                EventHandler<MouseEvent>
```

Comment: I would never, ever recommend using your `Application` subclass instance as an event handler, but why don't you just implement `EventHandler<Event>`?

Comment: I tried adding a handler for the Event superclass and designate behavior using "instanceof" and "event.getSource()", but I just received a compile-time error. Apparently I need specific EventHandlers for different Event types.

Comment: Please post your code: this works fine for me. Why do you need to do this anyway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but not in the way that you are expecting.

You cannot, as far as I know, implement the same interface twice, even with different types.

`EventHandler<ActionEvent> and EventHandler<MouseEvent>` conflict with each other, that is why you end up with the error.

Like so...

```
class CustomEventHandler implements EventHandler<Event>{

    public void handleActionEvent(ActionEvent ke){
        //handle event
    }

    public void handleMouseEvent(MouseEvent me){
        //handle event
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(Event event) {
        //handle event testing
    }

}
```

Then you simply test if the Event is of mouse type or action type, then handle the event from that function.

Comment: Of course, there is no obvious advantage to this over the standard mechanism of having two different classes; though this does correctly answer the question as posed. There's no way to implement `EventHandler<MouseEvent>` and `EventHandler<ActionEvent>` in the same class, because after type erasure (i.e. at runtime) the two methods have identical signatures, and so are ambiguous.