# How to implement selection of Nodes in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, event-listener

I am very new JavaFX, started learning it yesterday. Spent the whole day reading through the documentation, but learned nothing...

Here is what I want to do, make a simple JavaFX application that creates a circle. On click its stroke turns orange (some color). On unlicked (click on anything other than that circle), the stroke turns (some color) white.

Here is my **pseudo code** what I have so far. **I want to make a separate class that creates a circle and handle the events** (important).

```
public class Something extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        MyCircle c1 = new MyCircle();
        c1.setCircle(20, 0, 0);

        TilePane root = new TilePane();
        root.getChildren().add(c1.getCircle());
        //Some kind of mouse event listener, not sure which one should be
        c1.getCircle().addEventListener(); //pseudo code

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Circle");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

This the class that should create a circle and handle all the events, such as, mouse click, mouse location, click and drag and stuff like that.

```
public class MyCircle implements EventHandler{
    Circle circle = new Circle();

    public void setCircle(int radius, int x, int y){
        circle.setRadius(radius);
        position(x,y);
        circle.setStrokeWidth(3);
        circle.setStroke(Color.valueOf("white"));
    }

    public Circle getCircle(){
        return circle;
    }

    public void position(int x, int y){
        circle.setTranslateX(x);
        circle.setTranslateY(y);
    }

    public void selected(){
        circle.setStroke(Color.valueOf("orange"));
    }

    public void unselected() {
        circle.setStroke(Color.valueOf("white"));
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(Event event) {
        if (event == MOUSE_CLICKED){ //pseudo code
            selected();
        }
        else if(event == MOUSE_UNCLICKED){ //pseudo code
            unselected();
        }
    }
}
```

Since I am very new to JavaFX, I'd much appreciate explanation as well. Thanks!

---

**EDIT:** This is my pseudo code, and I want to convert it into an actual working code. I am not sure how would I do that. Any help would be appreciated.

---

**ANOTHER EDIT:** Everything is a code except 3 marked places. Please look for my comment `Psuedo Code` within the code, where I need help to change the pseudo code into an actual code.

Comment: And what is the problem ? You just need an explanation of your code?

Comment: @BoHalim, its a pseudo code, I want to write it in a way that works.

Comment: meaning, I want to turn this pseudo code into actual working code. I am not sure how would I do that.

Comment: Looks like code to me.

Comment: I personally think you should avoid your MyCircle class and use anonymous inner classes. At least, until you have a better understanding of event handling.

Comment: Add your mouse listeners to your scene.

Comment: Use this answer as a starting point. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18597939/handle-mouse-event-anywhere-with-javafx

Comment: @SedrickJefferson, No its not all of it. Everything is code except 3 marked places. Look for my comment `Psuedo Code`, where I need help to change the pseudo code into an actual code.

Comment: I know how anonymous inner classes work. I also know the lambda notations as well. I want to learn how to do the event handling in a separate class.

Comment: This may help you some. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31794167/how-to-handle-multiple-event-types-from-one-class-in-javafx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Handling selection status of a Node requires some knowledge not available within the Node. You'll going to need to know whether the mouse event happened somewhere else (e.g. other Nodes or the root Pane), so you may have to pass questionable arguments to it.

In general, it's not a good idea to delegate mouse event handling to `MyCircle`. Instead it's better to specify the selection behavior in that class and delegate selection handling to a separate helper class which has enough knowledge to handle the problem. I  created this [gist](https://gist.github.com/omidzk/3ceeebf948a210def5ca6fb5f39e14ff) to show how this task can be done.

```
public class SelectionDemo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(createPane(), 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Parent createPane() {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        SelectionHandler selectionHandler = new SelectionHandler(root);
        root.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, selectionHandler.getMousePressedEventHandler());

        MyCircle c1 = new MyCircle(40, 40, 20);
        MyCircle c2 = new MyCircle(40, 100, 20);
        MyCircle c3 = new MyCircle(40, 160, 20);
        root.getChildren().addAll(c1, c2, c3);

        return root;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I borrowed and modified an interface from [jfxtras-labs](https://github.com/JFXtras/jfxtras-labs/blob/8.0/src/main/java/jfxtras/labs/scene/control/window/SelectableNode.java) to represent a selectable Node. It's good to have this interface to differentiate between selectable nodes and unselectable ones:

```
/**
 * This interface is based on jfxtras-labs <a href="https://github.com/JFXtras/jfxtras-labs/blob/8.0/src/main/java/jfxtras/labs/scene/control/window/SelectableNode.java">SelectableNode</a>
 */
public interface SelectableNode {
    public boolean requestSelection(boolean select);

    public void notifySelection(boolean select);
}
```

classes who wish to be selectable must implement this interface and specify their selection behavior in implementation of notifySelection method:

```
public class MyCircle extends Circle implements SelectableNode {
    public MyCircle(double centerX, double centerY, double radius) {
        super(centerX, centerY, radius);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean requestSelection(boolean select) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void notifySelection(boolean select) {
        if(select)
            this.setFill(Color.RED);
        else
            this.setFill(Color.BLACK);
    }
}
```

And finally the selection handler class:

```
public class SelectionHandler {
    private Clipboard clipboard;

    private EventHandler<MouseEvent> mousePressedEventHandler;

    public SelectionHandler(final Parent root) {
        this.clipboard = new Clipboard();
        this.mousePressedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                SelectionHandler.this.doOnMousePressed(root, event);
                event.consume();
            }
        };
    }

    public EventHandler<MouseEvent> getMousePressedEventHandler() {
        return mousePressedEventHandler;
    }

    private void doOnMousePressed(Parent root, MouseEvent event) {
        Node target = (Node) event.getTarget();
        if(target.equals(root))
            clipboard.unselectAll();
        if(root.getChildrenUnmodifiable().contains(target) && target instanceof SelectableNode) {
            SelectableNode selectableTarget = (SelectableNode) target;
            if(!clipboard.getSelectedItems().contains(selectableTarget))
                clipboard.unselectAll();
            clipboard.select(selectableTarget, true);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This class is based on jfxtras-labs
     *  <a href="https://github.com/JFXtras/jfxtras-labs/blob/8.0/src/main/java/jfxtras/labs/scene/control/window/Clipboard.java">Clipboard</a>
     *  and 
     *  <a href="https://github.com/JFXtras/jfxtras-labs/blob/8.0/src/main/java/jfxtras/labs/util/WindowUtil.java">WindowUtil</a>
     */
    private class Clipboard {
        private ObservableList<SelectableNode> selectedItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        public ObservableList<SelectableNode> getSelectedItems() {
            return selectedItems;
        }

        public boolean select(SelectableNode n, boolean selected) {
            if(n.requestSelection(selected)) {
                if (selected) {
                    selectedItems.add(n);
                } else {
                    selectedItems.remove(n);
                }
                n.notifySelection(selected);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void unselectAll() {
            List<SelectableNode> unselectList = new ArrayList<>();
            unselectList.addAll(selectedItems);

            for (SelectableNode sN : unselectList) {
                select(sN, false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use some of the in-built Java functions to help accomplish your task.

For example [CSS PsuedoClasses](http://www.guigarage.com/2016/02/javafx-and-css-pseudo-classes/) and [Toggles](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Toggle.html) managed by a [ToggleGroup](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ToggleGroup.html).

It isn't necessary to do it this way, the solution you have which does not use these other JavaFX features, is just fine.  It is just kind of neat to use some of the standard JavaFX functions.

[image: lights]

*LightApp.java*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LightApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        final Bulb[] bulbs = {
                new Bulb(),
                new Bulb(),
                new Bulb()
        };

        Scene scene = new Scene(new LightArray(bulbs));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

*LightArray.java*

```
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;

public class LightArray extends HBox {
    public LightArray(Bulb... bulbs) {
        super(10, bulbs);
        setPadding(new Insets(10));

        ToggleGroup toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();
        for (Bulb bulb: bulbs) {
            bulb.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
        }

        setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            if (event.getTarget() instanceof Bulb) {
                toggleGroup.selectToggle((Bulb) event.getTarget());
            } else {
                toggleGroup.selectToggle(null);
            }
        });

        getStylesheets().add(
                this.getClass().getResource("bulb.css").toExternalForm()
        );
    }
}
```

*Bulb.java*

```
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;

class Bulb extends Circle implements Toggle {
    private ObjectProperty<ToggleGroup> toggleGroup = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    Bulb() {
        super(30);
        getStyleClass().add("bulb");
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected.set(selected);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected.get();
    }

    @Override
    public BooleanProperty selectedProperty() {
        return selected;
    }

    public BooleanProperty selected =
            new BooleanPropertyBase(false) {
                @Override protected void invalidated() {
                    pseudoClassStateChanged(ON_PSEUDO_CLASS, get());
                }

                @Override public Object getBean() {
                    return Bulb.this;
                }

                @Override public String getName() {
                    return "on";
                }
            };

    private static final PseudoClass
            ON_PSEUDO_CLASS = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("on");

    @Override
    public ToggleGroup getToggleGroup() {
        return toggleGroup.get();
    }

    @Override
    public void setToggleGroup(ToggleGroup toggleGroup) {
        this.toggleGroup.set(toggleGroup);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectProperty<ToggleGroup> toggleGroupProperty() {
        return toggleGroup;
    }
}
```

*bulb.css*

```
.bulb {
    -fx-fill: lightslategray;
}

.bulb:on {
    -fx-fill: gold;
}
```

An additional common thing which is often done with JavaFX (and I haven't done here), is to make items which can be styled by CSS (e.g. Regions or Panes) and then apply the styling to them.  For example, instead of the Bulb extending Circle, it could extend StackPane and then the bulb shape could be customized in css via multiple layered backgrounds and svg shapes (this is how other similar things such as radio buttons are implemented).

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it... Simple and Easy

**Main Class**

```
public class Lab05 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        double width = 400;
        double height = 400;

        int num_of_circles = 5;
        int radius_of_circles = 20;

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        for (int i = 0; i < num_of_circles; i++) {
            MyCircle temp = createCircle(radius_of_circles, (50 * i) + 1, 100);
            temp.setFrame(width, height);
            root.getChildren().add(temp.getCircle());
            temp.getCircle().addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, temp);
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, width, height);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Lab 05");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public static MyCircle createCircle(int radius, int x, int y){
        MyCircle circle = new MyCircle();
        circle.setCircle(radius, x, y);
        return circle;
    }
}
```

**MyCircle Class**

```
public class MyCircle implements EventHandler<MouseEvent>{
    private static double frameX = 0;
    private static double frameY = 0;
    private final Circle circle = new Circle();
    private static final List<Circle> CIRCLES = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setCircle(int radius, int x, int y){
        circle.setRadius(radius);
        position(x,y);
        circle.setStrokeWidth(3);
        circle.setStroke(Color.valueOf("white"));
        CIRCLES.add(circle);
    }

    public void setFrame(double x, double y){
        frameX = x;
        frameY = y;
    }

    public Circle getCircle(){
        return circle;
    }

    public void position(double x, double y){
        if ( x < frameX && x > 0)
            circle.setCenterX(x);
        if ( y < frameY && y > 0)
            circle.setCenterY(y);
    }

    public void selected(){
        CIRCLES.stream().forEach((c) -> {
            c.setStroke(Color.valueOf("white"));
        });
        circle.setStroke(Color.valueOf("orange"));
    }

    public void unselected() {
        circle.setStroke(Color.valueOf("white"));
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        if (event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED){
            selected();
        }
        else if (event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED){
            position(event.getX(), event.getY());
        }
    }
}
```