# Outline Shape3d javafx with mouse event

Tags: java, javafx, 3d, javafx-3d

Many 3d programs uses an outline to hint the user when 3d object is selected .

is there a way to mimic that behavior in javafx ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Outline with a scaled 3d object with front faces culled**

[image: culledfaces javafx]

In this aproach . A 3d object is instansiated with the class type of [`PickResult`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/PickResult.html) node when mouse is entered on a `Group` node , that object has the same sizes of the picked one and the same translations ( in this case is just x axis )  but is slightly scaled (1.1). So , the 3d object is bigger and it is in the same spot but is not overlaping the shape3d underneath beacuse any face looking toward the camera is culled with [Culface.FRONT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/CullFace.htmlhttps://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/CullFace.html) enum in `Shape3d.setCullFace()` . Finally , when mouse exits pickresult node the 3d object is removed from group's children allowing next iterations . This is a single class  functional javafx app you can try

App.java

```
public class App extends Application {

    private Shape3D outLine;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Shape3D sphere = new Sphere(0.45);
        PhongMaterial sMaterial = new PhongMaterial(Color.CORAL);
        sphere.setMaterial(sMaterial);
        sphere.setTranslateX(-1.1);
        Shape3D box = new Box(0.9, 0.9, 0.9);
        box.setTranslateX(1.1);
        box.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(Color.PALEGREEN));
        Shape3D cylinder = new Cylinder(0.45, 0.8);
        cylinder.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(Color.PALEVIOLETRED));
        PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);
        camera.setTranslateZ(-5.5);

        Group group3d = new Group(camera, box, sphere, cylinder);

        Scene scene = new Scene(group3d, 640, 480, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
        group3d.setOnMouseExited((t) -> {
            group3d.getChildren().remove(outLine);
        });
        group3d.setOnMouseEntered((t) -> {

            PickResult pickResult = t.getPickResult();
            Node intersectedNode = pickResult.getIntersectedNode();

            if (intersectedNode instanceof Sphere) {

                outLine = new Sphere(((Sphere) intersectedNode).getRadius());
                outLine.setTranslateX(intersectedNode.getTranslateX());
                group3d.getChildren().add(outLine);

                outLine.setCullFace(CullFace.FRONT);
                outLine.setScaleX(1.1);
                outLine.setScaleY(1.1);
                outLine.setScaleZ(1.1);

            }
            if (intersectedNode instanceof Cylinder) {
                Cylinder c = (Cylinder) intersectedNode;
                outLine = new Cylinder(c.getRadius(), c.getHeight(), c.getDivisions());
                outLine.setTranslateX(c.getTranslateX());
                group3d.getChildren().add(outLine);

                outLine.setCullFace(CullFace.FRONT);
                outLine.setScaleX(1.1);
                outLine.setScaleY(1.1);
                outLine.setScaleZ(1.1);

            }
            if (intersectedNode instanceof Box) {
                Box b = (Box) intersectedNode;
                outLine = new Box(b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(), b.getDepth());
                outLine.setTranslateX(b.getTranslateX());
                group3d.getChildren().add(outLine);

                outLine.setCullFace(CullFace.FRONT);
                outLine.setScaleX(1.1);
                outLine.setScaleY(1.1);
                outLine.setScaleZ(1.1);

            }
        });
        scene.setCamera(camera);
        scene.setFill(Color.AQUA);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("outline javafx");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

**Note**  Shape3d objects scale from its very center . If this method will be implemented with custom MeshView objects , those meshes needs to scale at its center as well

Comment: Is adding the `camera` to the two groups essential? Sorry to impose, but I hadn't seen this usage before. Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: No it isn't  in this case .I ussually add a camera in a separate group  for moving camera implementation . my bad . is not nescesary in this case